# ios keyBoardShow with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard

In my Code, every time keyboard pop out, tableView will be push up, so I can see the bottom of tableView. But the top three or four cell will be hide behind the view. The top of scrollView seems to be cut when keyboard is out.

How can I hold my tableview complete see when texting?

Here is my code...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
-(void)keyboardShow:(NSNotification *)note{
  CGRect keyBoardRect=[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  CGFloat deltaY=keyBoardRect.size.height;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue] animations:^{
  self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -deltaY);
  }];
}
-(void)keyboardHide:(NSNotification *)note{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue] animations:^{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  }];
}
```

scroll to the bottom after adding a text to a cell.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(self.data.count-1) inSection:0];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than transforming the view when the keyboard shows, shrink it by adjusting its frame:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-deltaY);
self.view.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: Yes,your are right. I think you mean that use "CGRectMake" instead. It's works :) Thank you!